How to remove the line coming below the top grid row of my WPF application
I am trying to design an application with two rows on top that are of the same colour, however when I run it, no matter what the content is in the top row, there is always a line that separates it from the row below it.
My current code is as follows:
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="DarkSlateGray" ShowGridLines="False">
        <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid>
                <Rectangle Width="30" Height="30" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="#2F2F2F" ></Rectangle>
                <Image Width="30" Height="30" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Image>
            </Grid>
            <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Center">Title</TextBlock>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="DarkSlateGray" ShowGridLines="False">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="RadioButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource NavButton}"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <RadioButton Grid.Column="0" Content="Home" VerticalAlignment="Center" Checked="RadioButton_Checked" Tag="home" IsChecked="True"></RadioButton>
        <RadioButton Grid.Column="1" Content="System" VerticalAlignment="Center" Checked="RadioButton_Checked" Tag="system"></RadioButton>
        <RadioButton Grid.Column="2" Content="Troubleshoot" VerticalAlignment="Center" Checked="RadioButton_Checked" Tag="troubleshoot"></RadioButton>
        <RadioButton Grid.Column="3" Content="Support" VerticalAlignment="Center" Checked="RadioButton_Checked" Tag="support"></RadioButton>

    </Grid>

</Grid>

And the line is coming like this below the top row:
I have messed around with the contents of this row and even left it blank with no elements in it, however, this line persists. How do I remove it?

Is there any other code which modifies the XAML styling? As i tested your code and it looks fine. And which version are you using?
However, maybe some external desing source modifies the styling of the grid, you could try to apply Margin="0" on both Grids.

No nothing else, I'm using .Net 8

And what about this part: BasedOn="{StaticResource NavButton}" where does this StaticResource come from?

Ah my bad, that's defined above as

Properties SnapsToDevicePixels and/or UseLayoutRounding may be responsible for that effect if they are set to True. Try to set them False and check if that helps.
<Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="False" UseLayoutRounding="False">
    ...
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="DarkSlateGray" SnapsToDevicePixels="False" UseLayoutRounding="False">
        ...
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="DarkSlateGray" SnapsToDevicePixels="False" UseLayoutRounding="False">
        ...
    </Grid>
</Grid>

Revert this change after checking if that was the source of the problem.
As a solution move Background="DarkSlateGray" to the outer <Grid> and add Background="White" where the "Hello" text is.
The problematic line is not a line - this is lack of DarkSlateGray background between two <Grid>s, mixed with white background undernach. The gap between grids is definitely bigger than 0.0, but less than 1.0 px.

This fixed it, thank you
